# How to configure ROS2 Control Hardware interface for differential drive motors for AMR with Roboteq FAMILY controller?

Tags: ros2, ros-control, hardware-interface

I want to control differential drive Autonomous Mobile Robot(AMR) with 2 Brushless DC Motors. Its a 2 wheels differential drive AMR. I have Roboteq FAMILY controller and was able to use the ROS2 driver , so can run the motors. I was using this github to make the ROS2 driver works  [ROS2 Roboteq driver](https://github.com/DoanNguyenTrong/roboteq_controller_ros/tree/galactic-devel).

So  I follow the ros2_control and the example2 from the demos(because is for the differential drive robot and try to create hardware interface header and cpp file.

The Roboteq ROS2 driver config file is

```
roboteq_controller_node:
  ros__parameters:
    serial_port: "/dev/ttyACM0" # Udev rule to make a virtual port that's associated to specific hw
    baudrate: 115200
    cmd_vel_topic: "/cmd_vel"

    closed_loop: true

    # For differential drive control (dual channel controller)
    diff_drive_mode: true
    wheel_circumference: 0.6594 # [m]
    track_width: .6223 # [m]
    max_rpm: 100.0 # [rpm]
    encoder_resolution: 1024

    # For querying data from the motor controller
    frequency: 50   #higher frequency (value is in ms)
    query:
      motor_amps : ?A 
      motor_command : ?M
      hall_count : ?Cb
      hall_speed : ?BS
      volts : ?V
      feedback : ?F 
      # battery_amps : ?BA
      # power : ?P          
      # fault_flag : ?FF  
      # motor_amps2 : ?MA
      # motor_command2 : ?FM
      # hall_count2 : ?FM
      # hall_speed2 : ?FS
      # volts2 : ?V
      # feedback2 : ?rmp 
      # battery_amps2 : ?PHA
      # power2 : ?sns          
      # fault_flag2 : ?S  
      # status_flag : ?FS
      # firmware_id : ?FID  
      encoder_count : ?C
      encoder_speed : ?S
```

So the hardware interface header is something like this

```
#ifndef DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT__DIFFBOT_SYSTEM_HPP_
#define DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT__DIFFBOT_SYSTEM_HPP_

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "hardware_interface/handle.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/hardware_info.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/system_interface.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_return_values.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/clock.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/duration.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/macros.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/time.hpp"
#include "rclcpp_lifecycle/node_interfaces/lifecycle_node_interface.hpp"
#include "rclcpp_lifecycle/state.hpp"
#include "diffdrive_ROBOT/visibility_control.h"

#include "diffdrive_ROBOT/wheel.hpp"

namespace diffdrive_ROBOT
{
class DiffDriveROBOTHardware : public hardware_interface::SystemInterface
{

struct Config
{
  std::string left_wheel_name = "";
  std::string right_wheel_name = "";
  float loop_rate = 0.0;
  std::string device = "";
  int baud_rate = 0;
  int timeout_ms = 0;
  int enc_counts_per_rev = 0;
  int pid_p = 0;
  int pid_d = 0;
  int pid_i = 0;
  int pid_o = 0;
};


public:
  RCLCPP_SHARED_PTR_DEFINITIONS(DiffDriveROBOTHardware);

  DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT_PUBLIC
  hardware_interface::CallbackReturn on_init(
    const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo & info) override;

  DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT_PUBLIC
  std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> export_state_interfaces() override;

  DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT_PUBLIC
  std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> export_command_interfaces() override;

  DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT_PUBLIC
  hardware_interface::CallbackReturn on_configure(
    const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & previous_state) override;

  DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT_PUBLIC
  hardware_interface::CallbackReturn on_cleanup(
    const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & previous_state) override;


  DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT_PUBLIC
  hardware_interface::CallbackReturn on_activate(
    const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & previous_state) override;

  DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT_PUBLIC
  hardware_interface::CallbackReturn on_deactivate(
    const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & previous_state) override;

  DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT_PUBLIC
  hardware_interface::return_type read(
    const rclcpp::Time & time, const rclcpp::Duration & period) override;

  DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT_PUBLIC
  hardware_interface::return_type write(
    const rclcpp::Time & time, const rclcpp::Duration & period) override;

private:

  ROBOTComms comms_;
  Config cfg_;
  Wheel wheel_l_;
  Wheel wheel_r_;
};

}  // namespace diffdrive_ROBOT

#endif  // DIFFDRIVE_ROBOT__DIFFBOT_SYSTEM_HPP_
```

And the cpp file is

```
#include "diffdrive_Robot/diffbot_system.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_type_values.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

namespace diffdrive_Robot
{
hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRobotHardware::on_init(
  const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo & info)
{
  if (
    hardware_interface::SystemInterface::on_init(info) !=
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS)
  {
    return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
  }


  cfg_.left_wheel_name = info_.hardware_parameters["left_wheel_name"];
  cfg_.right_wheel_name = info_.hardware_parameters["right_wheel_name"];
  cfg_.loop_rate = std::stof(info_.hardware_parameters["loop_rate"]);
  cfg_.device = info_.hardware_parameters["device"];
  cfg_.baud_rate = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["baud_rate"]);
  cfg_.timeout_ms = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["timeout_ms"]);
  cfg_.enc_counts_per_rev = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["enc_counts_per_rev"]);
  if (info_.hardware_parameters.count("pid_p") > 0)
  {
    cfg_.pid_p = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["pid_p"]);
    cfg_.pid_d = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["pid_d"]);
    cfg_.pid_i = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["pid_i"]);
    cfg_.pid_o = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["pid_o"]);
  }
  else
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"), "PID values not supplied, using defaults.");
  }
  

  wheel_l_.setup(cfg_.left_wheel_name, cfg_.enc_counts_per_rev);
  wheel_r_.setup(cfg_.right_wheel_name, cfg_.enc_counts_per_rev);


  for (const hardware_interface::ComponentInfo & joint : info_.joints)
  {
    // DiffBotSystem has exactly two states and one command interface on each joint
    if (joint.command_interfaces.size() != 1)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' has %zu command interfaces found. 1 expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.command_interfaces.size());
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }

    if (joint.command_interfaces[0].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' have %s command interfaces found. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.command_interfaces[0].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY);
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }

    if (joint.state_interfaces.size() != 2)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' has %zu state interface. 2 expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.state_interfaces.size());
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }

    if (joint.state_interfaces[0].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' have '%s' as first state interface. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.state_interfaces[0].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION);
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }

    if (joint.state_interfaces[1].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' have '%s' as second state interface. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.state_interfaces[1].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY);
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }
  }

  return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> DiffDriveRobotHardware::export_state_interfaces()
{
  std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> state_interfaces;

  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
    wheel_l_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &wheel_l_.pos));
  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
    wheel_l_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &wheel_l_.vel));

  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
    wheel_r_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &wheel_r_.pos));
  state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
    wheel_r_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &wheel_r_.vel));

  return state_interfaces;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> DiffDriveRobotHardware::export_command_interfaces()
{
  std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> command_interfaces;

  command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
    wheel_l_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &wheel_l_.cmd));

  command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
    wheel_r_.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &wheel_r_.cmd));

  return command_interfaces;
}

hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRobotHardware::on_configure(
  const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"), "Configuring ...please wait...");
  if (comms_.connected())
  {
    comms_.disconnect();
  }
  comms_.connect(cfg_.device, cfg_.baud_rate, cfg_.timeout_ms);
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"), "Successfully configured!");

  return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRobotHardware::on_cleanup(
  const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"), "Cleaning up ...please wait...");
  if (comms_.connected())
  {
    comms_.disconnect();
  }
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"), "Successfully cleaned up!");

  return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}


hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRobotHardware::on_activate(
  const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"), "Activating ...please wait...");
  if (!comms_.connected())
  {
    return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
  }
  if (cfg_.pid_p > 0)
  {
    comms_.set_pid_values(cfg_.pid_p,cfg_.pid_d,cfg_.pid_i,cfg_.pid_o);
  }
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"), "Successfully activated!");

  return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRobotHardware::on_deactivate(
  const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"), "Deactivating ...please wait...");
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRobotHardware"), "Successfully deactivated!");

  return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

hardware_interface::return_type DiffDriveRobotHardware::read(
  const rclcpp::Time & /*time*/, const rclcpp::Duration & period)
{
  if (!comms_.connected())
  {
    return hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR;
  }

  comms_.read_encoder_values(wheel_l_.enc, wheel_r_.enc);

  double delta_seconds = period.seconds();

  double pos_prev = wheel_l_.pos;
  wheel_l_.pos = wheel_l_.calc_enc_angle();
  wheel_l_.vel = (wheel_l_.pos - pos_prev) / delta_seconds;

  pos_prev = wheel_r_.pos;
  wheel_r_.pos = wheel_r_.calc_enc_angle();
  wheel_r_.vel = (wheel_r_.pos - pos_prev) / delta_seconds;

  return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
}

hardware_interface::return_type diffdrive_Robot ::DiffDriveRobotHardware::write(
  const rclcpp::Time & /*time*/, const rclcpp::Duration & /*period*/)
{
  if (!comms_.connected())
  {
    return hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR;
  }

  int motor_l_counts_per_loop = wheel_l_.cmd / wheel_l_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate;
  int motor_r_counts_per_loop = wheel_r_.cmd / wheel_r_.rads_per_count / cfg_.loop_rate;
  comms_.set_motor_values(motor_l_counts_per_loop, motor_r_counts_per_loop);
  return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
}

}  // namespace diffdrive_Robot

#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp"
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(
  diffdrive_Robot::DiffDriveRobotHardware, hardware_interface::SystemInterface)
```

So im not sure if this is correct. Also Do i need this PID configuration as Roboteq controller already take care of it??Any help

Answer (score 1):

I wrote hardware interface recently for Roboteq SBL controller. You can find source file here with all the necessary files. [diffdrive_roboteq_sbl](https://github.com/Hercogs/diffdrive_roboteq_sbl/blob/main/hardware/diffbot_system.cpp)

Regarding PID - if you use closed loop control, then Roboteq controller uses internal PID values which you set when chose closed loop mode, so you do not need to use them in hardware interface if you are not planning to override them. If you use open loop control, then it is another story.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine at first glance.

But without the details of `ROBOTComms comms_` or your `Wheel` class it's hard to tell if you use this API correctly.

I don't understand your question regarding PID: `comms_.set_pid_values` seems to set the PID gains of the underlying controller, why would you not set them?